# IllegalArgumentException while reading an image in java

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

I am trying to get a image as the icon for a JFrame window, but I got this error while loading the image.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at quest2.WindowFrame.<init>(WindowFrame.java:21)
    at quest2.WindowFrame.main(WindowFrame.java:39)
```

This is the code, but I cut out a few lines that do not pertain to this question.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;  
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WindowFrame extends JFrame{

    private static BufferedImage BufImage;
    Image image;  //The image for the icon of the frame

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WindowFrame() {

        //Get a Image for the Icon
            try {
            BufImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/src/quest2/Logo.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(BufImage);
        image = ii.getImage();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(720, 480);
        setTitle("Quest 2");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setIconImage(image);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new WindowFrame();
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so if anyone could give me help with this, that would be great.

Comment: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), be able to help you somewhat in this direction :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src` won't exist at run time...

You should be using...

```
getClass().getResource("/quest2/Logo.png")
```

instead

**Updated**

You should also be catering for the situation where the image may be `null`, for example...

```
try {
    BufImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/quest2/Logo.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setResizable(false);
setSize(720, 480);
setTitle("Quest 2");
if (BufImage != null) {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(BufImage);
    image = ii.getImage();
    setIconImage(image);
}
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
```

Also, changing the `resizable` state of the frame will affect it's size, you should do this before setting the frames size (preferably using `pack`) and call `setVisible` last

You may also want to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and ensure that the UI is initialised within the context of the Event Dispatcing Thread

Comment: Also moving the image setting code inside try with a null check for BufImage  maybe be a good idea.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Or at least deal with the fact that `BufImage` could be `null` at all